# Temperature-induced wavelength shift of optical coatings?

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, visible-light, refraction, optical-materials

Optical coatings designed for reflection or anti-reflection are made of many thin layers which will expand when heated. What will the effect be on the wavelengths the coating will reflect when the coating is heated?

For a first guess, magnesium fluoride has a thermal expansion coefficient of about 10 µm/m/K , so the affected wavelengths could be red-shifted by 1E-5/K? But this doesn't take into account refractive index changes. Does anyone know of experimental data on actual coatings?

Comment: I bet the interaction between materials is so complicated that the best way is to just take a bunch of data points and try to figure out how your specific optical material behaves at various temperatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since found [this pdf](http://www.cvimellesgriot.com/products/documents/technicalguide/interference_filter_coatings.pdf) from CVI Melles Griot giving a temperature coefficient of 0.016 nm/°C at 400 nm, increasing to 0.027 nm/°C at 820 nm. This will vary between coating types but it is enough to get started.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it depends on application. For example, broadband dielectric mirrors sold by ThorLabs do not specify their temperature-dependence for the obvious reason of redshift magnitude you specified. Even narrowband dielectrics and laser line mirrors don't usually specify this. However, other devices such as crystal optics for wavemixing can strongly depend on ambient temperature, and dedicated ovens or servo-controls may be recommended for reliable performance.

Are you planning on manufacturing an optic, or are you just looking to buy them? Usually, any reputable distributor or manufacturer will specify whether temperature-dependence can be an issue with an element, but if in doubt you can always ask the maker.

Comment: Good answer but I wouldn't rely on the distributor to specify any temperature dependences.  If you're looking to buy a component and aren't sure what a change in temperature will do call up the distributor, or even better call the manufacturer (if not the same).

Comment: I'm trying to diagnose some spectral artefacts which I'm nearly certain are caused by temperature shifts. I would like to have some realistic parameters to sanity check the calculations, and 1E-5/K figure I pulled out of the air looks a bit small to explain the effect. I'll check with the manufacturer.